# promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems

Tags: r, r-caret, caret

I want to perform feature selection using Caret's Genetic Algorithms. The outcomes `y` is the `subtype` column in `clin.info`. The rownames of `clin.info` corresponds to the colnames of `met.deconv.relative`.

```
library(caret)
obj <- gafs(x = met.deconv.relative, 
            y = as.factor(clin.info[,"subtype"]),
            iters = 100)
```

Traceback:

```
Error in gafs.default(x = met.deconv.relative, y = as.factor(clin.info[,  : 
  promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?
```

Input:

```
> dput(met.deconv.relative[1:10,1:10])
structure(list(TCGA.Y8.A8S1.01 = c(0.550828247772734, 0, 0.331193755024188, 
0.0397937067092402, 0, 0, 0.0123106244532931, 0.0429490913967326, 
0.020395397358106, 0), TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.00723028292077139, 0.414997365852491, 0.577772351226738, 0), 
    TCGA.Y8.A8RY.01 = c(0.867244835975172, 0, 0, 0.0180277687859282, 
    0, 0, 0.0733546839226409, 0.0413727113162587, 0, 0), TCGA.Y8.A897.01 = c(0.200014611553106, 
    0, 0.307165518738796, 0.243888136397938, 0, 0, 0.24893173331016, 
    0, 0, 0), TCGA.Y8.A896.01 = c(0.699516108255348, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.300483891744652, 0, 0, 0), TCGA.Y8.A895.01 = c(0.688926101620937, 
    0, 0.19723212494978, 0, 0.0058672819613848, 0, 0.0704367767769461, 
    0.0375377146909525, 0, 0), TCGA.Y8.A894.01 = c(0, 0.481688485576903, 
    0, 0.356287482154964, 0, 0, 0.162024032268133, 0, 0, 0), 
    TCGA.WN.A9G9.01 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), TCGA.V9.A7HT.01 = c(0.721893680326815, 
    0, 0, 0.141791379325406, 0.0210361494183095, 0, 0.11527879092947, 
    0, 0, 0), TCGA.UZ.A9Q0.01 = c(0.403189710486653, 0.0991244095085273, 
    0, 0.142388711545978, 0, 0, 0.355297168458842, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c("Monocytes", 
"Dendritic Cells", "Macrophages", "Neutrophils", "Eosinophils", 
"Regulatory T cells", "Naive T cells", "Memory T cells", "CD8 T cells", 
"NK cells"), class = "data.frame")

> dput(clin.info[1:10,14:15])
structure(list(subtype = c("2a", "1a", "1a", "1a", "1b", "2b", 
"1a", "2a", "1a", "1c"), type = c("2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
"1", "2", "1", "1")), row.names = c("TCGA.Y8.A8S1.01", "TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01", 
"TCGA.Y8.A8RY.01", "TCGA.Y8.A897.01", "TCGA.Y8.A896.01", "TCGA.Y8.A895.01", 
"TCGA.Y8.A894.01", "TCGA.WN.A9G9.01", "TCGA.V9.A7HT.01", "TCGA.UZ.A9Q0.01"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: There is no column `subtype` in your example data `clin.info` ?

Comment: oops sorry. It's now edited

Comment: The error does not occur if the `gafsControl = ` parameter is supplied to `gafs()`.

Comment: Also, you may need to transpose your met.deconv.relative df (i.e. `t(met.deconv.relative)`); per [the docs](https://rdrr.io/cran/caret/man/gafs.default.html): "An object where samples are in rows and features are in columns. This could be a simple matrix, data frame or other type (e.g. sparse matrix).'